# TeamCity show changes from snapshot dependencies

Tags: dependencies, teamcity

I have a TeamCity build (A) that does only checkout and msbuild steps and provides it's binaries as output to three other builds.

Build B is quick running tests, that take about 5 minutes, B uses A output through snapshot/artifactory dependencies.

Output from A is also used in two other build task which are long running tests and installer creation.

For now, when some tests in B fail, I don't see changes made to A from withing test job B (or c or D) which caused that fail.

Is possible to display changes made to build task A when displaying test results for task B. So we can easily see which changes have broken the build?

Right now it is also possible, but requires some more digging into TC buildlogs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In B, go to the *Version Control Settings* | *Show advanced options* | check *Show changes from snapshot dependencies*.

That should do it. (Given that the title of your question is identical with the name of the option, I wonder if you already know about this checkbox and it's not working for some reason?)

Comment: Thanks, I've found that checkobx and it's doing it's job!

Answer (score 3):

Following on from the accepted answer of Version Control Settings | Show advanced options | check Show changes from snapshot dependencies. 
The dependent builds do **not** need a VCS Root to show changes from dependencies.